# Log out from all browser tabs when one tab is logged out

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 4 I have created one application using angular 4 where I have a login page and home page.When I log in with my credentials I will navigate to home page.

If I my application is opened in multiple tabs when I log out from one tab any click on other tab in application should redirect to login page as it happens in gmail.

Can any one please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code sample so we can know how you handel your authorization and how you store user data

Comment: can u please tell me how to refresh or reload the url or page in other tabs when a click event occurs inside the application if user is logged out from one tab.this will solve my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send a request to the server to invalidate the authentication token (not related to Angular) and all tabs need to regularly check on the server if their token is still valid and log out themselves if not.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Please maintain a authentication token, it will help you. It is not related to Angular 4

**Example:**

1. Create a token and store in the database while login
2. Check the token for each backend call whether the token is available or not
3. Once token is not available redirect to login page
4. While log out remove the token from database
5. You opened multiple tabs, log out from one tab, then try to click from another tab, it will check for the token, once the token is not available in the database it will automatically redirect to login page

This is the simple solution for your question

Answer (score 0):

In case you store token/login info in the local storage, you can listen to changes
 like that:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
  // there is a problem with IE (in all other browsers event not emitted in current window) 
  // so need to check that it is the other tab that emitted event
  // and avoid infinite loop
  if (!document.hasFocus() && event.key === environment.localStorageTokenKey) {
    // do stuff here
    window.location.pathname = '/';
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: You are free to put it wherever you need it @RNKushwaha! For example you can add it after a `<body>` tag, but you need to add `<script>` tag around it or you can place it into a separate js file.